# How to represent an extensible 2D array in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures, types

What I need is a table that can be extended with new columns (as well as rows) at any time. Using DataTable seems an overkill as I don't need any relational functionality nor data binding while I do need high speed of operation on fairly big amounts of data (e.g. store a million of rows with some columns and be able to add e.g. a hundred of new columns quickly).

As for now the best way seems to be pre-allocating a simple 2D array of redundant size. Are there any better ways?

Comment: Does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, I think it can be used for this but I doubt reasonable idea, @ElectricRouge

Comment: you *can* create your own slimmed-down thing similar to `DataTable`, but ultimately: *is it worth it*? Yes, `DataTable` is overkill and ugly, but: will it do the job? is there a problem with using `DataTable` that you want to avoid? Side note: a million rows and wanting to add a hundred more columns at runtime is *always* going to be painful. Have you considered using an actual database table here?

Comment: "Are there any better ways?" - depends on what you're storing! a sparse array-like-thing may be appropriate if a lot of the grid is empty, for example; and what are the data types? always the same for every cell? or does it vary by column?

Comment: @MarcGravell The data type is the same for every cell. It is not sparse though prone to grow.

Comment: @Ivan and which grows more often? rows? or columns? from the sound of it, I would be *tempted* to represent this as a column store - i.e. the table is something like an `List<YourType[]>`, where each item in the list is a **column** (not a row) - and oversized so there is room to add more rows without having to resize (at which point you resize *all* the columns). Each "row" is really just a tuple that contains the "table" and the row index, so `this[int col] => table[col][row];` You can use a `List<List<YourType>>` if that is easier... any use?

Comment: Yes, I think I'll go this way, @MarcGravell. It just didn't come into my mind to transpose the model.

Answer (score 2):

There is no inbuilt class that provides this functionality barring the already mentioned `DataTable`, but you could build your own basic one without too much fuzz:

```
public class Table<T>
{
    private readonly List<List<T>> columns;

    public Table()
    {
        columns = new List<List<T>>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Columns => columns.Select(c => c.Select(r => r));
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Rows
    {
        get
        {
            IEnumerable<T> getRow(int index)
            {
                foreach (var c in columns)
                {
                    yield return c[index];
                }
            }

            for (var row = 0; row < Count; row++)
            {
                yield return getRow(row);
            }
        }
    }

    public int Count => columns.Count == 0 ? 0 : columns[0].Count;
    public T this[int row, int column]
    {
        get
        {
            return columns[column][row];
        }
        set
        {
            columns[column][row] = value;
        }
    }

    public void AddRow()
    {
        foreach (var c in columns)
        {
            c.Add(default(T));
        }
    }

    public void AddRow(params T[] values)
    {
        if (values.Length != columns.Count)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        for (var column = 0; column < columns.Count; column++)
        {
            columns[column].Add(values[column]);
        }
    }

    public void DeleteRow(int row)
    {
        foreach (var c in columns)
        {
            c.RemoveAt(row);
        }
    }

    public void AddColumn()
    {
        var newColumn = new List<T>();

        for (var rows = 0; rows < Count; rows++)
        {
            newColumn.Add(default(T));
        }

        columns.Add(newColumn);
    }

    public override string ToString()
        => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Rows.Select(c => string.Join(";", c)));
```

If each column can hold its own type, then the same code would work simply making it non generic and as the internal store a `List<List<object>>`.

*DISCLAIMER*: This code hasn't been tested, it looks good but its bound to have some stupid bug...